# Ruby on Rails link_to using variable_name_path and controllers:variable_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two different syntax both referring to same url

```
 <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>

<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'articles' %>
```

What is the differences between the two approaches , which one should be use when. where is articles_path stored ?

Comment: run `rake routes` in console and see the magic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both syntax does the same thing they will take you to `/articles`.

**Which ones better**

Since both does the same thing so it really depends on you which one to use but if you look at [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) it says 1st syntax

```
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

is better because **it's less verbose**.

**What is articles_path**

articles_path is just a [rails helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) which *rails creates for you when you make a route.* As `@nithin` suggested if you run rake routes in your terminal you can see those helper methods.

*If you'll use articles_url it will give you pull url like `domain/articles` and if you'll use articles_path then it'll give you a relative url `/articles`*